# How can you publish a CSV as feature layer when creating a feature class in ArcGIS online?

Tags: arcgis-online, csv, feature-service

According to ESRI's instructions, one is supposed to place a check mark next to a box which states "publish this file as a feature layer."However, this check box does not appear anywhere in the "Item from my computer" box when one initially brings the file into ArcGIS online. How would I locate this check box? Is this ESRI's error or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2):

Once you browse for the csv file the window will change to accommodate the file type. Because there are different file types that can be added, instead of listing all the possible configuration options ArcGIS Online waits to see the file type you have inputted and then gives you the available options.

To summarise, the steps are as follows;

1)Select "add item"

2)Select "item from my computer"

3)Browse for your csv

4)Once the csv is selected the window will change and the "publish this file as a feature layer." is now visible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 something to note is this doesn't work on a free public account, it has to be added on an organizational or paid type account to get the option to make it a feature service.